# "Around a mouth full" phrase

Tags: word-choice

Context: Around a mouth full of food, he mumbled, "Thank you."

"Around a mouth full" reads weird to me. However, it sounds fine but like "around a mouthful of," which seems natural to my ears. But is "around a mouth full of" valid?

Comment: Seems valid; you've basically elided "a mouth (which was) full of food".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion is that the words had to *'go around' the food in his mouth* in order to get out, not that the food was 'around' his mouth.

Note the difference between a 'mouthful' (one word) and a 'mouth full'. A 'mouthful' is a rough measurement of food - the amount that might fit in one's mouth, whereas "a mouth full" can only mean a mouth that is full. We sometimes use "the mouth" to refer to only the lips, especially when related to speaking; however, the mouth is of course the oral cavity. The food was in his mouth, and he was speaking 'around' that food.